# Use a Label Value in Calculations

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Can you use the value of a label in calculations. For example I have some textboxes

Lbl__Text box__Total

$100__5____$500

$50__100__$5000

$20___4____$20

So when the user enters in the text box it is calculated in the total. 
Can it be done with an expression or do I need to use VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the reasons of WHY you would be doing that, yes. Use VBA to reference the control

[image]

You can reference any value of any form control within ms access. See below for and example. Simply add this code into the AfterUpdate Event of your textbox where the user enters the data.

```
Me.tbxTotal.Caption = (Me.lblStatus.Caption * Me.tbxStatus.Caption)
```

EDIT:
With further insight on the issue, different use cases have different scenarios. I just have never encountered a desire for that functionality an always take my values from textboxes.

Also corrected my code. Shows the importance of testing before answering a question

Comment: I am getting an error on this part Me.lblStatus".Value"

Comment: What is the error you are receiving, and what is the value in the label?

Comment: The Value is 100 and the error is "Member or Data Member Not Found"

Comment: If `Me.lblStatus` is a label, use its `Caption` instead of `Value`.  [A label doesn't have a `Value` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.label#properties)

Comment: . Perfect. Can I ask Why I shouldn't be doing this? I am using the labels to represent the different denomination of a currency. When the user inputs the count of each currency it is stored in a table. Is there a better way to achieve this. – raziel3 1 hour ago

Answer (score 0):

A label caption is text, so first thing to do, is to convert that to a number by stripping the $ sign.

Then, create expressions to use as *ControlSource* for the total textboxes.

Thus, they would be:

```
=Val(Mid([NameOfLabel1].Caption,2))*[NameOfTextBox1]
=Val(Mid([NameOfLabel2].Caption,2))*[NameOfTextBox3]
=Val(Mid([NameOfLabel3].Caption,2))*[NameOfTextBox3]
```